# An error on using a template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to develop an application to read regexes. I'm in Visual C++ 2015 and I'm getting an intellisense error that T is undefined for the last 2 lines. I'm trying to use a template so I can declare the Parent variable in the structure. If I don't use the T in the last 2 lines intellisense says there is no arguement list for the 2 RegEx declarations. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
//Declared globally

template<typename T> 

struct RegEx {
        T *Parent;
        bool isEmpty;
        string literal;
        int lit_len;
        bool is_Lit_only;
        bool is_Parent;
        bool is_Or;
        bool is_Star;
        bool is_Star_or;
        bool is_Or_star;
        int subRE_len_a;
        int subRE_len_b;

    };

RegEx<T> RE[200];
RegEx<T> Base;
```

Comment: when instantiating a template, you have to specify its template parametrs, e.g. `RegEx<char> RE[200];`, so that `T` is substituted by `char`

Comment: So would I say RegEx <struct> RE[200]? Or how would I do that?

Comment: It's probably polymorphism you want.

Comment: if by `struct` you mean a type name, then yes

Comment: I put <char> instead of <t> and it compiled. Is that correct? Or do I need polymorphism? How would I do that?

Comment: we have to little information to solve this. how is it intended to be used?

Comment: <struct> doesn't work.

Comment: My program does some evaluations on the RegEx's if it can parse them correctly.

Comment: I just didn't use the template and declared in the structure RegEx *Parent and it compiled with no errors or warnings. I think my original error came from not using the pointer with the variable.